# Почему в более поздней версии 4.0.2 не работает стиль кнопки?

Tags: android, java

Сделал стиль для кнопки. Применил. В версии 2.3.7 (Андроид) все работает. А в версии 4.0.2 нет, вообще не видит стиль.

Проверял на реальных устройствах. В чем может быть причина?

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
        <gradient android:angle="90.0"
            android:endColor="#009FD0"
            android:startColor="#00008B"
            android:type="linear" />

        <corners android:radius="15.0dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient android:angle="90.0"
            android:endColor="#6495ED"
            android:startColor="#0000FF"
            android:type="linear" />

        <corners android:radius="15.0dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Еще описание темы нужно добавить. Всех файлов с темой.

Comment: в какой папке лежит этот файл? Мне кажется, что там проблема с values-xx именем папки

Comment: этот файл лежит в папке res\drawable\btn_style1.xml

Comment: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
в Манифесте у всех Ативити прописано

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причина была в следующем:

файл main.xml есть не только в папке layout, но и в папке layout-v11.
Содержимое их немного отличалось. 
Насколько я понял, именно из папки "layout-v11", файл с разметкой основного Активити подгружался, если версия api android была больше 10.